# How to use MySQL's REPLACE Syntax in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Can I use REPLACE without patching ActiveRecord or executing raw SQL in Rails 4?
I just want to save a record only if there is no corresponding data in its table.

I know `find_or_create_by` method but I guess this generates twofold queries, SELECT and INSERT.
If there is another INSERT query between the two, it will fail, right?
Or am I worrying too much? (The system I'm working on is not a mission critical one.)

Comment: What is the "another INSERT query" you're referring to?  I think you need to provide a little bit more detail about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPLACE` is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard.

As ActiveRecord tries to be database agnostic as much as possible, I don't think adding behaviour of a specific database is a priority... last mention I found of people asking for it was on 2009 [Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/_FqBo6bt8Ho).

Anyway, I'm not sure if using `REPLACE` would be the same as using `find_or_create_by`.
From MySQL Reference:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

`find_or_create_by` behaves differently, since it will leave the record as it is, if it already exists:

```
# File 'activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb', line 200

def find_or_create_by(attributes, &block)
  find_by(attributes) || create(attributes, &block)
end
```

Also, as you mentioned, `find_or_create_by` can have a race condition if you don't use it properly. You should use it like this (from [ActiveRecord Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation%3afind_or_create_by)):

```
begin
  CreditAccount.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry
end
```

Comment: raviolicode, thank you so much. As a Rails novice, I'm going to stick to the Rails way, using find_or_create_by instead of REPLACE.
And thank you too for letting me know how to trap a UNIQUE constraint exception and retry.